# On chang rate listner android Rating bar (Android)

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to do action when user change Rating bar stars 
i can't find any thing like that onchanging rating bar or on select stars i couldn't find any thing about that anyone have an idea about that

Comment: you should do something before you ask :/ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html see this

Comment: ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,  boolean fromUser) {
            //Do your work
        }
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've searched in wrong places I think. All is presented in Android Api docs:

```
void    setOnRatingBarChangeListener(RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener listener)
```

[RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html)